# MAX882 battery protection

Tags: voltage, batteries, protection, hysteresis

I am thinking of using the [MAX882](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/linear-regulators/MAX882.html) IC to protect my battery from overdischarging. What I could not understand from the datasheet I provided is that, if I use the STBY pin to set a threshold for my battery max discharge, when the battery reaches that voltage, and the output turns off (i.e. no current drawn anymore), wouldn't the battery voltage go up? As a result, wouldn't my circuit turn on and off with the battery voltage swinging around the threshold voltage set at STBY?

To sum up, there seems to be no hysteretic or latching functions, that could prevent the swinging from happening. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read the datasheet correctly, there is **7mv** of hysteresis for Standby comparator.

[image]

If the battery voltage slightly goes up after shutdown and the STBY pin input voltage exceeded the upper STBY threshold of 1200mV+7mv than your regulator will start and again after some battery drainage the voltage crosses the lower STBY threshold it will shutdown.

But this process will repeat until your battery will be not able to cross the upper STBY threshold Voltage.